# WSSF application, catch exception level

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, exception

At which level in a Web Service Software Factory or any N-Tier application is correct to catch .NET exceptions, and throw custom exceptions (Faults) ? I did it in service implementation and created a fault contract for every service operation, but i'm not shure is well.
**Regards,**
 
**Sergiu.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the best place to catch exception. Usually top layer when control leaves the code is the best place to get the exception. It will contain all inner exception and complete stack trace.